# Chromium menus not rendered properly in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, chromium, menu

Have an old computer at home on which I installed lubuntu 16.04 after some recommendation from people in this forum [Extremly Slow Dell Optiplex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833355/extremely-slow-computer-dell-optiplex-270) to recap, the system is:

- Dell Optiplex 270
- Pentium 4 at 3 GHz [32 bit]
- 2 GB RAM
- 250 GB SSD [newly installed, Toshiba THNSN256GBST]
- NVIDIA P118 FX 5200.

The system has worked impressively well with lubuntu right out of the box.  There have been just a couple of issues that I would like to fix.  Here is one.

As you can see in the attached screen capture, the menus on Chromium are not rendering properly (black boxes only).  The current window decoration theme is *Mikachu* and the Widget (Custom Look and Feel) is *Clearlooks* but the same happened with the default theme window decoration theme as well as *Adwaita* for Widget.  Whether I maximise the window or I keep it half size, the issue is the same.

The issue persists whether I use hardware acceleration or not (option within Chromium).

Note that the horizontal and vertical scroll bars have suffered the same fate.

[image]

Comment: @DK Bose: OK.  I have now tried the *Adwaita* theme (selected from Custom Look and Feel > Widget).  By the way, it was not installed by default (the icons were but not the gtk theme).  I installed via `synaptic`.  I have modified the description above to reflect this.  As for the *Advanced Settings*, I struggled for a while to find this as I thought this was a setting within lubuntu but it turns out it is one of the settings within Chromium.  Well, I turned it off and the issues seems to persist.

Comment: @DKBose : I tried again removing hardware acceleration and restarting Chromium and this time it seems to have worked.  I can see the menus and the scrollbars.  Not sure why the first time it did not take.  Unfortunately, it seems to have changed the theme I was using. [Indeed, I was using some theme within Chromium.  Now it was removed across all my computers.]  Not a big deal, I can live without it.    
Thank you for your continuous help, much appreciated.

Comment: @DKBose: If you want you can answer the question with the hardware acceleration part so we can wrap this one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround could be to turn off hardware acceleration in the browser. To do so, go to `advanced settings` (near the bottom of the page) in Chromium's `chrome://settings` and turn off "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting GPU Rasterization to a different value.

Access `chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization` and select ***Force-enabled for all layers***.
Keep the browser updated to the latest version.